# When to NOT use Atomic Operations?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, atomic

I can think of reasons when it doesn't matter, and 1 situation where you may NOT want to use them which is when you want to test a design for behaviour with non-atomic operations.

What are some other reasons? Specifically I am working on a project that is having some rare race conditions, because a test is not using atomic increments. I am wondering, why would I not just always use atomic increments when a function for it already exists?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me turn your question around on you. If you write your program so that workers are spawned off as new *processes* rather than new *threads*, you don't ever have to worry about atomic updates to shared memory because processes don't share memory. So instead of asking "why not always use atomic operations?" wouldn't it be sensible to instead ask  **why not always use processes instead of threads**?

Comment: Interesting point, I suppose the problem is the same thing as why not to use atomics, resources such as memory/speed are limited.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because atomics are slower. They slow down the calling thread, and they may slow down other threads as well, potentially even ones not accessing the same atomics. They may also inhibit the compiler from performing certain reordering optimizations that it would otherwise perform.

Comment: Also, of course... Just using atomics everywhere doesn't actually do anything to improve the thread safety (and may lead to deadlocks, if you skip correct analysis because of it).

Comment: @JamesKanze, atomics are not necessarily locks-based

Comment: @Leeor While that's true, they're also not guaranteed to _not_ use locking, and there are other ways to lock up (or put all active threads into busyloops, which isn't any more helpful). Program correctness is a ***global*** property.

Comment: @DonalFellows, right, I just think using std::atomic and getting in some cases an mfence instead of a lock could be very confusing. I'd count that as an argument against std::atomic.

Answer (score 1):

Atomic operations are potentially, and likely, more expensive than their non-atomic equivalent.  In cases where synchronization between threads isn't needed, for instance updating an unshared local, atomiticy adds unnecessary overhead and should be avoided.